# When does this equality hold: $(A + B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$? Where $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Given
$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 1\\
b & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$
, what are the values of $a$ and $b$ if $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2$?

I think if the equality holds then $AB + BA = 0$.

$
AB =
\begin{bmatrix}
2a-b & 3\\
2a-b & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$
and
$
BA = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2a + 2 & -a-1\\
2b-2 & -b + 1
\end{bmatrix}
$

$\therefore
AB + BA =
\begin{bmatrix}
4a-b+2 & 2 - a\\
2a+b-2 & 4-b\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I think there are no values of $a$ and $b$ for which $AB+BA = 0$.

Is this correct, or are there any mistakes in my solution?

Comment: You are on the right track!

Comment: Correct! But you might want to argue why no such $a,b$ exist.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: There are no mistakes but I wouldn't view it as complete.  I'd like you to tell me why $(A+B)^2 = A^2 + B^2 \implies AB + BA = 0$.  And I'd like you to tell me why $\begin{bmatrix}
4a-b+2 & 2 - a\\
a+2b-2 & 4-b\\
\end{bmatrix} = 0$ is impossible.  (Both are easy to answer.... and your answer so far is correct).

Comment: In case you are interested in the general case, look up anticommutativity.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realize that the matrix multiplication is not necessarily commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are no such values.

For $AB+BA=0$, we must have $$a=2,b=4$$ and $$4a-b+2=0$$ that is simply not possible.